# Array_Splice not removing items, returning every item from array normally

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-splice

I've been attempting to grab a list of images from a folder, then use a $_GET value to limit how many items receive. I first, tried to 'foreach' the array_splice function but I've learned that returns the REMOVED items, I for example, want to get the value of '2' and then return images 50-100, 2, 100-150, ex.. Maybe even better would be having a value of 1 would return images 0-50, 2, 51-101, and 3 102-152. Just every value returns 50 images that do not collide-- you get the idea haha.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$limit = 50;

if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = (int)1;
} else {
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
}

$start = (int)(($page*$limit)-$limit);
$end = (int)($page*$limit);

$origin = scandir('imgs/');
$images = array_diff($origin, array('.', '..'));
array_slice($images, $end, $start);
echo $start . ' ' . $end;
?>

<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($images as $img) {
        echo $i . ' ';
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You should use `$images = array_slice($images, $end, $start);`. Also `$end = (int)($page*$limit) - 1;`

Comment: Trying that seems to not work. https://hastebin.com/kezibizeto.xml

Comment: You don't seem to have changed the `array_slice` code

Comment: So sorry-- I don't fully understand. https://hastebin.com/mubofaqila.xml Here's my code, and it's returing 0- Pagenumber*50. Thank you for helping though!

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying attention to your `array_slice` parameters. You need `$images = array_diff($origin, array('.', '..'));` *and then* `$images = array_slice($images, $start, $limit);`. That should give you 0-49 for page 1, 50-99 for page 2, 100-149 for page 3 etc. Note you don't actually need `$end` at all

Comment: I'm so so sorry to keep bothering you, but for pages 1++, I always get 0-49. Here's the code https://hastebin.com/oxewamiyaw.xml , and once again I'm very sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: Your code looks fine. You should `var_dump($_GET);` to make sure it has what you think it should in it.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5Qs2NmP.png It looks fine, I'm wondering what's wrong. The page seems to work.

Comment: You need to start with `$i = $start;`, not `$i = 0;`

Comment: This looks like it's working... thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate that you went our of your way to help, have a wonderful night man honestly.

Comment: No problem at all. I'm glad it's working.